# コンテキストファイルのdocBaseに設定するディレクトリがわかりません。

Tags: jsp

jspの環境構築です！

**前提・実現したいこと**

コンテキストファイルのdocBaseの設定をし、Tomcatで表示したいです。

**発生している問題・エラーメッセージ**

```
HTTPステータス 404 - /hello/hello.jsp

type ステータスレポート

メッセージ /hello/hello.jsp

説明 The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M13
```

**該当のソースコード**
【**C:\Users\ユーザー名\Downloads\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M13\conf\localhost\hello.xml**】

```
<Context path="/hello"
docBase="c:/users/ユーザー名/jsp-sample/hello"/>
```

【**C:\Users\ユーザー名\jsp-sample\hello\hello.jsp**】

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=Shift_JIS" %>

<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World!</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World!</h1>

<%
out.println(new java.util.Date());
%>

</body>
</html>
```

おそらくエラーの原因はdocBaseだと思うのですが何が間違っているのか、
まったくわかりません。

ご教示お願いします。

マルチポスト
https://teratail.com/questions/55962

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決

JSPファイルの置き場所が異なるようです。 
Webアプリケーションとして作成するなら以下のようになるでしょう。

C:\Users\ユーザー名\jsp-sample\hello\WebContent\hello.jsp

https://teratail.com/questions/55962